# I can't proceed in creating Developer Account in wp

Tags: windows-phone, marketplace, dreamspark

I want to deploy my app in Windows Phone store but Microsoft still asking credit card account and I don't have that.

I use Dream Spark account for student because it is free. Is there other way of creating an developer's account for free without asking a credit card info? I don't have any info that I can provide.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know exactly how DreamSpark account works but I know it should be linked to a school or university. Maybe you can get in touch with them.

Answer (score 1):

I am beginner in Windows Phone development. I faced same issue that I had Dreamspark account, but did have credit card. I googled around and could not find any solution. But, for a try, I simply entered my ATM Debit Card (that was Visa card, may work with Mastercard as well ), it worked!!!!!. Actually, they charge small amount(refundable, for my case Rs. 2) for verification and it doesnot matter whether it is Debit Card or Credit Card.
(Correct me, if I am wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

Well you have one option in this case: you have to look for MSP(Microsoft Student Partners) community from your University and you may apply to enter in MSP.

Once you are a MSP member you will gain for free a Developer Account.

More information : [Microsoft Student Partners](http://www.microsoftstudentpartners.com/).